# Bitcoin Transaction signing using Javacard

Tags: bitcoin, javacard

I am trying to sign below mentioned bitcoin transaction using javacard

```
0200000001e4055643d3aeb058f80fb2b31c33ebd8761c7c6d7432646401a24a82bcca50f30000000000fdffffff0100ca9a3b000000001976a914ad35829229a3dcddfcaa0ffea7425a522aa202c488ac00000000
```

I am able to sign it via javacard applet which is capable of signing using ECC sec256k1 and also give us back the publickey.

But when i use the signed transaction in bitcoin cli it says...

> mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed
> CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)

What is wrong here may be i am signing wrong data?